# why scheduled job using corn is not working in django?

Tags: python, django, cron

I've used https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/ tutorial to schedule corn job but it is not working:
I added

```py
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'django_crontab',
    ]
    
    CRONJOBS = [
        ('*/1 * * * *', 'allActivitiesApp.cron.sendNotification', '>> /path/to/log/file.log'),
    ]
```

In allActivitiesApp -> corn.py:

```py
    from .models import *
    
    def sendNotification():
        # notificationList = dateBasedNotificaton.objects.filter(scheduleDate = date.today())
        obj = test(name="working")
        obj.save()
        obj.refresh_from_db()
        # print("sending notifications/messages")
        return "success"
```

but it is not doing anything when I tried to get logs I found:

```
    Feb  1 13:17:01 karanyogi CRON[43137]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
    Feb  1 13:17:01 karanyogi CRON[43138]: (karanyogi) CMD (/home/karanyogi/E-Mango/env/bin/python /home/karanyogi/E-Mango/Jan27New/eMango/manage.py crontab run 60a198cfdc0c719d07735a708d42bafb >> /path/to/log/file.log # django-cronjobs for iStudyMain)
    Feb  1 13:17:01 karanyogi CRON[43136]: (karanyogi) MAIL (mailed 71 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
    Feb  1 13:18:01 karanyogi CRON[43267]: (karanyogi) CMD (/home/karanyogi/E-Mango/env/bin/python /home/karanyogi/E-Mango/Jan27New/eMango/manage.py crontab run 60a198cfdc0c719d07735a708d42bafb >> /path/to/log/file.log # django-cronjobs for iStudyMain)
    Feb  1 13:18:01 karanyogi CRON[43266]: (karanyogi) MAIL (mailed 71 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
    Feb  1 13:19:01 karanyogi CRON[43285]: (karanyogi) CMD (/home/karanyogi/E-Mango/env/bin/python /home/karanyogi/E-Mango/Jan27New/eMango/manage.py crontab run 60a198cfdc0c719d07735a708d42bafb >> /path/to/log/file.log # django-cronjobs for iStudyMain)
    Feb  1 13:19:01 karanyogi CRON[43282]: (karanyogi) MAIL (mailed 71 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
    Feb  1 13:20:01 karanyogi CRON[43437]: (karanyogi) CMD (/home/karanyogi/E-Mango/env/bin/python /home/karanyogi/E-Mango/Jan27New/eMango/manage.py crontab run 60a198cfdc0c719d07735a708d42bafb >> /path/to/log/file.log # django-cronjobs for iStudyMain)
    Feb  1 13:20:01 karanyogi CRON[43436]: (karanyogi) MAIL (mailed 71 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
    Feb  1 13:21:01 karanyogi CRON[43789]: (karanyogi) CMD (/home/karanyogi/E-Mango/env/bin/python /home/karanyogi/E-Mango/Jan27New/eMango/manage.py crontab run 60a198cfdc0c719d07735a708d42bafb >> /path/to/log/file.log # django-cronjobs for iStudyMain)
    Feb  1 13:21:01 karanyogi CRON[43788]: (karanyogi) MAIL (mailed 71 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
    Feb  1 13:22:01 karanyogi CRON[43809]: (karanyogi) CMD (/home/karanyogi/E-Mango/env/bin/python /home/karanyogi/E-Mango/Jan27New/eMango/manage.py crontab run 60a198cfdc0c719d07735a708d42bafb >> /path/to/log/file.log # django-cronjobs for iStudyMain)
    Feb  1 13:22:01 karanyogi CRON[43808]: (karanyogi) MAIL (mailed 71 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

I didn't get any logs in mail.

How can I fix this..?

Comment: Looks like all your problems come from the fact that you think it's `corn` instead of `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in your file name:

```
In allActivitiesApp -> corn.py:
```

The filename should be `cron.py` instead of `corn.py`.

2nd reason may be that you have not run the commands:

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

to add all defined jobs from CRONJOBS to crontab

To show current active jobs of this project:

```
python manage.py crontab show
```

Comment: file name is cron.py I wrote that by mistake and I already run python manage.py crontab add.

Comment: python manage.py crontab show is showing the job but job is not executing.  ----------------Currently active jobs in crontab:
60a198cfdc0c719d07735a708d42bafb -> ('*/1 * * * *', 'allActivitiesApp.cron.sendNotification', '>> /path/to/log/file.log')

Comment: Please help if you have anything else than this. I am using ubuntu

Comment: this shows that your cronjob is running fine. there may some issue with send email function.
Test your send email function manually.

Comment: But if job is running why it is not creating instance of test model..?

Comment: that you need to test manually first and please also confirm that the model name is 'test' or 'Test'.